# Passing references type variable as method parameter

Tags: java

After running the code below I get this output:
Eve
1200

Could anyone explain me why the value of Person type variable is being changed and value of Integer type variable is not? 
I have already read this:

1. www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2000-05/03-qa-0526-pass.html
2. www.yoda.arachsys.com/java/passing.html#formal

but I don't get why with Person and Integer types it works different.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object person = new Person("Adam");
        Object integer = new Integer("1200");

        changePerson(person);
        changeInteger(integer);

        System.out.println(person);
        System.out.println(integer);
    }

    private static void changeInteger(Object integer) {
        integer = 1000;
    }

    private static void changePerson(Object person) {
        ((Person)person).name="Eve"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: http://creativekarma.com/ee.php/weblog/comments/value_types_in_java/

Comment: To post code on Stack Overflow, indent each line by 4 spaces. You can select the code in your question and click the toolbar button, or hit Ctrl+K, to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java, [primitive types](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) (such as integer) are always handled exclusively by value, and objects (such as your Person) and arrays are always handled exclusively by [reference](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch02_10.htm).

If you pass a primitive **the value will be copied**, if you pass a reference type **the address will be copied**, hence the differences.

If you follow those links above and/or do a bit of googlin' you'll find out more.

Comment: In the link given by you it is really good described what is going on. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In the `Integer` case, you're changing the value of the parameter itself (which is local to the method).  In the `Person` case, you're changing the value of a field inside the parameter.  That field is part of the object, and so it's visible to the caller.

Comment: Take a List type variable, put it as a method parameter and you will be able to change it. I think mihirsm is on the right way with this statement:
Aslo, do keep in mind that Integer (and so are other primitive wrappers) mutable. Any time you need to assign a new value to the ref var, JDK will create a whole new object.

Answer (score 1):

In `changeInteger()` when you do integer = 1000 a new object is created and assigned a local variable **integer**. 
So if you do

```
person = new Person();
person.name="Eve";
```

in `changePerson()`

you will get the same behavior as for integer.

PS: The old references are lost once you assign it to newly created objects inside the function.

Comment: OK. The field name from Person class is not final. In integer class value of class instance is stored in field int which is set as final. If I set the field name as final I am not able to change its value in changePerson() method. But I still fill that I don't know all the mechanism...

Comment: I did a test with StringBuilder type. This type store string in an array which is not declared as final! There was no problem to pass an instance of StringBuilder to a method and append something to the StringBuilder variable. 
I think that for all primitives and their wrappers JDK do extra job I was not aware. I need to some exact explanation...

Comment: As I said when you do integer = 1000 you create a new object which is similar to integer = new Integer("1000")

Comment: Am I right that this happens because Integer is a wrapper for int and store the value in final field?

Answer (score 1):

Just for any future reference,the accepted answer isn't the correct answer in this case (although the links do provide enough informaiton to get the correct answer). The OP problem has nothing to do with primitves vs objects. In the exampe code given, there are no primitives used, both integer and person are full objects. Answers below that answer are more helpful. The key is that the parameter variable (i.e. the variable used to store the passed in parameter in the methods) is given the current value of variable used in the method call. Objects are stored by reference in   Java, so they point to the object rather than storing the object directly. So the parameter variable in the method is given this pointer address and uses this to access the object details. So if the method changes the object, this is the same object that the calling code is pointing towards and so both places will see the change. In the integer example, when you say integer  = 1000, it is overwriting the passed in pointer with a new pointer to a new Integer object - you have lost the connection to the original object.

Note that is no way to change an Integer object once it has been created (e.g. no .setValue() method) so there is no way to write the code in a way that could change the original Integer object.

Answer (score 0):

Your code below compiles? It needs a cast.

```
private static void changeInteger(Object integer) {
    integer = 1000;
}
```

Your `integer` will be changed if it was embedded in another `object` e.g. `Person`.

EDIT :

Wrong on the compilation issue. In Java, references are copied by value. So in first case the reference get pointed to different memory. In the second case, `name` comes as part of `Person`. Since you are changing name through `Person` without changing `Person`, change in `name` is reflected outside method. Hope this helps.

Comment: It compiles under with jdk 1.6 no casting is needed.
What I already get is that value on Integer type is stored in final field. When field name from Person class is changed to final then the code does not compile...

Answer (score 0):

In the `changeInteger()` method you are assigning a completely new object (1000) to the reference variable `integer`. But the reference variable `integer` in the `main()` method still points to the old object (1200). Thus the print() statement in the main() method prints the old value (1200)

However, in the `changePerson()` method the reference variable `person` still points to the old object. Just that a value of one of its field is being change.

Aslo, do keep in mind that Integer (and so are other primitive wrappers) mutable. Any time you need to assign a new value to the ref var, JDK will create a whole new object.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why in changeInteger() case new object assigned and in changePerson() case not?

Comment: behind the scenes 

i = 1000 

will be same as 

i = new Integer(1000)


on the other hand, if, lets say, there was a method 

i.value = 1000

then the main() would have printed 1000

Answer (score 0):

In changePerson() you change the given object itself via his public name property.
In changeInteger() you change the local Integer Object;

Put a System.out.println(integer); inside the changeInteger() function and you will see, that the Integer changes, but only in function scope..

```
private static void changeInteger(Object integer) {
    integer = 1000;
    System.out.println(integer);
}
```